# React native FONT loading without expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

with expo-font we can render fonts asynchronously when the app loads here is the example.
Like wise how we can render fonts without expo.

```js
import {AppLoading} from 'expo'
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
import React from 'react';

state = {
  isFontLoaded:false
}
  
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "Bold":require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.otf'),
    "Medium":require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.otf'),
    "Regular":require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf'),
  })
  this.setState({isFontLoaded:true})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - create a folder called "assets", inside it create "fonts" folder and put all your ttf files inside it.

2 - create a file in the root called: `react-native.config.js` and put insdie it :

```
        module.exports = {
                project: {
                        ios: {},
                        android: {}
                },
                assets: ['./assets/fonts']
        };
```

3 - run this command: `npx react-native link`
4- usage: in stylesheet use fontFamily:"font name", and also fontweight:''